# Нужна ли запятая перед «и»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

*Книга состоит из двух частей: первая — от А до Б, и вторая — С.*

Comment: Вы уж определитесь: либо А, Б, В, либо A, B, C.

Comment: От А до Б — это потому, что между ними дистанция? И второе: названия должны быть в кавычках.